# Redis Javascript Async Function

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, asynchronous, redis

I have an array of Id' and i need to get the details for each of them.

i currently have this.

```
const redis = require('redis');

const redisClient = redis.createClient(process.env.REDIS_PORT, process.env.REDIS_HOST);

const arrayList = [
  { id: 3444 },
  { id: 3555 },
  { id: 543666 },
  { id: 12333 },
];

async function getDetails(element) {
  await redisClient.hgetall(element.id, (err, user) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log('Something went wrong');
      // Handle Error
      return err;
    }
    console.log('Done for User');
    return user;
  });
}


arrayList.forEach((element) => {
  console.log('element');
  await getDetails(element).then((res) => {
    // Do Something with response for each element
  });
});
```

This is the response i get right now. its not async. What am i doing wrong please.

```
element
element
element
element
Done for User
Done for User
Done for User
Done for User
```

Answer (score 0):

So how things go on in async/await is, you create an async function and inside that function you await for other operations to finish. You call that async function without await OR you wrap it(func call) inside another async function.

```
arrayList.forEach((element) => {
  console.log('element');
  let returnedPromise= getDetails(element);
  console.log("Promise after getDetails function", returnedPromise);
});
```

This code change should resolve the error.

Answer (score 0):

`Array.forEach()` does not wait for promises to execute before moving to the next item.

You could instead use a for-loop in an async function, like so:

```
async function main() {
  for (const element of arrayList) {
    const response = await getDetails(element);
    // do something with reponse for each element
  }
}

main()
  .then(() => /* on success */)
  .catch((err) => /* on error */);
```